Google App Engine with PHP 8.3 and openssl legacy support
I changed my PHP version to PHP 8.3 on the Google App Engine platform, and I noticed that Google changed the OpenSSL version, with legacy support being disabled by default.
I'm using a .p12 file created on Windows, and when I tried to call openssl_pkcs12_read, the error "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported" is displayed.
Can I enable legacy support?
I tried to find another PHP function as a replacement, and I also looked for some php.ini configuration options.
